# What does dataframe.loc[;, variable, variable] indicate?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I understand that with `dataframe.loc[:, "variable1", "variable2"]` - `variable1` is the start, `variable2` is the end so what is the purpose of the `;`?

Specifically, this line of code has confused me
https://www.kaggle.com/code/apapiu/regularized-linear-models

```
all_data = pd.concat(
    (
        train.loc[:, 'MSSubClass': 'SaleCondition'],
        test.loc[:, 'MSSubClass': 'SaleCondition']
    )
)
```

Comment: It means that we are taking all rows `:` and all columns from `MSSubClass` to `SaleCondition`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please pay close attention to the question and to the code. "I understand that with dataframe.loc[;, "variable1", "variable2"] - variable1 is the start, variable2 is the end so what is the purpose of the ;?" - this does not make sense, because the actual line of code that you show **does not have `;` in it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code snippet (arguments of both invocations of *loc*):

- `:` means: all rows,
- `'MSSubClass':'SaleCondition'` means take columns from *MSSubClass* to
  *SaleCondition* (inclusive, i.e. without the last column named *SalePrice*).

Actually, you should have written:

```
dataframe.loc[:, "variable1":"variable2"]
```

Note that the above row does not contain any ";".